# How to check if certain characters aren't in a string?

Tags: python, list, radix

```
import os

class Converter(object):

def dec_to_any(self, a, b):
    self.values = {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5", 6: "6", 7: "7", 8: "8", 9: "9", 10: "A", 11: "B", 12: "C", 13: "D", 14: "E", 15: "F", 16: "G", 17: "H", 18: "I", 19: "J", 20: "K", 21: "L", 22: "M", 23: "N", 24: "O", 25: "P", 26: "Q", 27: "R", 28: "S", 29: "T", 30: "U", 31: "V"}

    self.universal = []
    self.temp_uni = []

    while a != 0:
        if a < b:
            self.universal.append(self.values.get(a, "unavailable"))
            a -= a
        else:
            self.universal.append(self.values.get((a % b), "unavailable"))
            a //= b

    for i in range(len(self.universal) + 1):
        self.temp_uni.append(self.universal[-i])
    del self.temp_uni[0]

    self.universal = ""
    for i in self.temp_uni:
        self.universal += str(i)

    return self.universal

def any_to_dec(self, a, b):
    a = int(a, b) #problem part 3 start and end

    return a

def display(self):
    print("Hello and welcome to the base converter\nHere is the menu:\n\t0 - close\n\t1 - convert\n\n")

def main(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.display()
            self.option = int(input("Please select one: "))
            while self.option > 1 or self.option < 0:
                os.system("cls")
                self.display()
                self.option = int(input("Please select one: "))
            os.system("cls")
            break

        except:
            os.system("cls")
            pass

    if self.option == 1:
        while True:
            try:
                self.base1 = int(input("Please enter a base to convert from (2-32): "))
                while self.base1 < 2 or self.base1 > 33:
                    os.system("cls")
                    self.base1 = int(input("Please enter a base to convert from (2-32): "))
                break

            except:
                os.system("cls")
                pass

        while True:
            try:
                self.number = str(input("Please enter a number to convert: ")).upper()
                break

            except:
                os.system("cls")
                pass

        while True: #problem part 1 start
            try:
                self.base2 = int(input("Please enter a base to convert to (2-36): "))
                while self.base2 < 2 or self.base2 > 37:
                    os.system("cls")
                    self.base2 = int(input("Please enter a base to convert to (2-36): "))
                break

            except:
                os.system("cls")
                pass #problem part 1 end

        os.system("cls")

        self.return_val = self.any_to_dec(self.number, self.base1) #problem part 2 start and end
        self.return_val = self.dec_to_any(self.return_val, self.base2)

        print(self.number, "in base", self.base1, "would be", 

self.return_val, "in base", self.base2)

start = Converter()

start.main()
```

That is the code, for reference. I am making a base converter where the user picks a base to convert from and to and enters a number, the converter spits out the converted number. My dilemma is that the user can enter base 2 for example and exceed what they have entered ultimately rendering an error, which I try and prevent by adding an if statement to check which base they are in and a while loop saying don't proceed until no error causing characters are present. but that is exhausting to type out. Is there a more automated method to do it? Like:

```
base_2 = ["0", "1"]
```

If anything is present that's not in `base_2`:

```
  some prevention code....
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That sure is a lot of code... Can you break down the problem to show only the relevant parts?

Comment: Besides being a lot of code, it's not indented properly.

Comment: What's the maximum base you support?  Base 36 is a natural one (0-9 + a-z) or base 62 (0-9 + a-z + A-Z).  The you could come up with a master string `"01...9ab...zAB...Z"` that has all of the characters that could be in a valid input integer of any base.  Then, a number of base `n` can only have "digits" from the first `n` characters of that string.

Comment: You can write an explicit loop over `for ch in numeral: if ch not in base_2: raise ValueError("invalid base-2 digits")`. You can simplify that, and speed it up, if you think about it in terms of sets; e.g.: `digits = set(numeral); if digits & base_2 != digits: raise ValueError("invalid base-2 digits")`. (Or, even more simply, `if not base_2 <= set(digits): raise ValueError(…)`)

Comment: @chrisz "base32" the string encoding is different from the normal base-32 numeral system.

Comment: @chrisz That's a good point, I didn't notice that. Obviously, if you want to support existing encodings, that don't follow some general pattern, you'll have to determine the character sets for each one individually.

Comment: @sacul i have added #tags saying '#problem № start and then end'. i.e. #problem number 1 start. the first problem hash tag is the user can enter a number after the base they have chosen, if they entered a number that exceeds the chosen base, i.e. they have chosen base 2 and entered a 010101023, 23 being the problem. this number and base if fed into the function where there is the second hash tag. this function refers to the 3rd hash tag. This is where the error occurs, because int() refuses to take bases that don't match the number and generates an error.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh thats a really good idea but how eould i write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can get the digits and alphabet from the `string` module.  The below is for case-insensitive literals for bases 1-36.

```
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase

characters = digits + ascii_lowercase


def is_valid(literal, base):
    valid_digits = characters[:base]
    return set(valid_digits).issuperset(literal.lower())


is_valid('01010101', 2)
# True
is_valid('100101a', 2)
# False
is_valid('DeadBeef', 16)
# True
is_valid('123z', 16)
# False
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I seriously didn't think that SETS of all things would be the answer. and the smart [:base] index assignment. seriously, THX alot, epic algorithm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!